# How to get floating div with 100% height to always stay 100%

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a left float with 100% height and right float with 100%. Everything works fine till I fill one side up with text and the other side will just stop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want them to keep expanding? If not, consider setting a `max-height` for both.

Comment: Yea I want the right and left to both stay 100% height no matter how much text is in either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `css` tables after inserting a parent `div` for both columns. For example:

Your HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
    <div id="rightcolumn"></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#parent{display:table-row}
#leftcolumn{display:table-cell}
#rightcolumn{display:table-cell}
```

Answer (score 2):

try with below code.

in HTML

```
<div class="content">
<!-- Start UI Leftside -->
    <div class="ui-leftside">
        <div class="ui-cont">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End UI Leftside -->
<!-- Start UI Rightside -->
    <div class="ui-rightside">
        <div class="ui-cont">
            <p>Add Text here how long you want</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<!-- End UI Rightside -->
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
}

.ui-leftside {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
}

.ui-cont {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px 0 10px;
}


p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.ui-rightside {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the floating divs in an enclosing div with `position: relative`, then give the left float with `position: absolute` to make sure it goes to the bottom.

The left floating div needs a reference height to start with. The outer enclosing div allows a 100% height div to take the full height of the container.

I have changed the right float to `float: right` and given the header with a `z-index: 2`.

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsjDr/embedded/result/)